# How to use VS2015 to debug android native app if I have to use NDK r11?

Tags: visual-studio, android-ndk, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to develop Android Application. Now VS2015 is using NDK r10e, which has some bug.

NDK r11 has been released in last month, then I switch to r11, but can't debug.

Does anyone know the the process about how visual studio debug android native app, or what can I do if I want to use visual studio to debug with NDK r11?

Answer (score 1):

Solved

Undefine VS_NdkRoot so that I can use the old NDK provide by Visual Studio to proceed debug. It looks fine.